# Magento - Select stock status in category->getProductCollection

Tags: magento, collections, stock

I am trying to get the stock status of all products within a particular category. My current code is below but `getIsInStock` is not part of the default collection. How can i get this value in the same way as `->addAttributeToSelect('product_type')`

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_cat_id)->getProductCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('product_type');

foreach ($collection as $product) {
    if( $product->getIsInStock() ) { 
        print $product->getProductType().' is in stock';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join your collection by :

```
$collection->joinField(
                        'is_in_stock',
                        'cataloginventory/stock_item',
                        'is_in_stock',
                        'product_id=entity_id',
                        '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
                        'left'
                        )
```

let me know if it helpes

Comment: actually ended up going down a different route qith `Mage::getModel('catalog/prodcut')->load($product->getId());` inside my for each loop to get the full list of product attributes available but this also does work